# Mattermost Test cases

Tags: go, reactjs, mattermost

I am a beginner for Mattermost.I have setup complete mattermost and it runs appropriately.Kindly let me know how can I run and test the test case files like 'post_test.go'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for running mattermost test you should run `make test` cause there are a few thing that need to be run first. sadly you can't run separate tests files

Answer (score 0):

You can change directory where the test file is located and then do something like:

`go test -test.run="^TestCreatePost$"`